# How calculate average values for lists in R tibble?

Tags: r, tibble

Let say I have R tibble

```
  df <- tibble(
    name = c("x", "y"),
    prob = list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6))
  )
```

How calculate average of values for "prob" field.

Expected result is a list with values c((1+4)/2, (2+5)/2, (3+6)/2) => c(2.5, 3.5, 4.5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Reduce` to get element-wise addition and divide it by number of rows in the dataframe.

```
Reduce(`+`, df$prob)/nrow(df)
#[1] 2.5 3.5 4.5
```

Other alternatives with `rowMeans` and `colMeans`.

```
colMeans(do.call(rbind, df$prob))
rowMeans(do.call(cbind, df$prob))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `tidyverse` solutions

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
   select(prob) %>%
   summarise(prob = reduce(prob, `+`)/n())
# A tibble: 3 x 1
   prob
  <dbl>
1   2.5
2   3.5
3   4.5
```